# How to configure logback.xml for custum log formatter

Tags: log4j, logback, formatter

```
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class Syslog4jPatternlayout extends PatternLayout {

    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        return "";
    } 
}
```

How to configure the `logback.xml` file to use this formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably use logback LayoutBase

```
public class Syslog4jPatternlayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {

  public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
      return "";
  }

}
```

And in logback.xml

```
<appender name="appender1" class="your appender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <layout class="com.kp.Syslog4jPatternlayout" />
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```